# Hapi - How to parse the payload to JSON?

Tags: json, swift

So I'm trying to study up on HTTP/TCP/IP Protocols, Nodejs, MongoJS,and MongoDB all at once. So I'm trying to figure out a couple things with the Hapi Web Framework. I am able to communicate with the server with my iOS simulator however, I can't seem to parse the payload right. I understand I could use parameters in the URL to send the information but I would like to use the payload.

So I end up with this being saved into Mongo.

```
(
    {
    "_id" = 5431f161bb859872034d2456;
    "{\"userLastNameKey\":\"Kwon\",\"userEmailKey\":\"email\",\"userFirstNameKey\":\"Michael\",\"userUsernameKey\":\"username\",\"userPasswordKey\":\"password\"}" = "";
},
    {
    "_id" = 5431fe5694ed4721046c1f8c;
    "{\"userLastNameKey\":\"Kwon2\",\"userEmailKey\":\"email2\",\"userFirstNameKey\":\"Michael2\",\"userUsernameKey\":\"username2\",\"userPasswordKey\":\"password2\"}" = "";
```

This is my hapi code for the call.

```
    // This will add a new user to the database
function addUser(request, response){

    db.usersCollection.save(request.payload, function (err, saved){
        if(err || !saved)
        {
            console.log("User not saved");
        } else 
          {
              console.log("User saved");
          }
    });
}
```

My end result I would like to try and get it to be like this

```
    (
    {
    "_id" = 5431f161bb859872034d2456,
    "userLastNameKey" = "Kwon", 
    "userEmailKey" = "email",
    "userFirstNameKey"= "Michael",
    "userUsernameKey" = "username",
    "userPasswordKey" = "password",
    }
)
```

Here's the iOS code

```
   NSDictionary *userData = [User userToDictionary: newUserInfo];
   NSData *userJSON = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: userData options: 0 error: nil]; 

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
 [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
 [request addValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // This will set up the url session
    NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: config];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest: request fromData: userJSON completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            if(error)
            {

            } else
              {

              }

          }];

          [uploadTask resume];
      }
```

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "_id" = 5431f161bb859872034d2456;
  "userLastNameKey" = "Kwon"; 
  "userEmailKey" = "email";
  "userFirstNameKey"= "Michael";
  "userUsernameKey" = "username";
  "userPasswordKey" = "password";
}
```

That is **NOT a JSON object**. You need to use commas instead of semicolons. and colons instead of equals. Your ID is also not a decimal number so it's probably best to make it a string.

Your object would look like :

```
{
  "_id" : "5431f161bb859872034d2456",
  "userLastNameKey" : "Kwon",
  "userEmailKey" : "email",
  "userFirstNameKey" : "Michael",
  "userUsernameKey" : "username",
  "userPasswordKey" : "password"
}
```

To parse a (well-formatted) JSON string, use : `var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSONstring);`

Comment: ok so the payload has a ' = "" ' at the end of it. Without that part the JSON parse works great. Do you know possibly where that = "" part comes from?

Comment: can you paste the new payload?

Comment: { '{"userLastNameKey":"Kwon6","userEmailKey":"email6","userFirstNameKey":"Michael6","userUsernameKey":"username6","userPasswordKey":"password6"}': '' }

Comment: the " :'' " at the end is throwing me off can you explain what that is?

Comment: it must be an error when you generate the string, can you add some code to your post so I can have a look? it looks like you're having the whole payload as a key, and ''(empty) as a value.

Comment: you want an array of user objects, [ {user:..., userkey...},{user1:...,userkey:...} ] but that's not what you generate. Show me how you create the payload and I should be able to fix it

Comment: I put my iOS code on my question thats how I generate my request